# How to move and scale an image right?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
            public function startScale():void {

                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

            }

            public function endScale():void {

                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

            }

            public function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {

                bigBall.width -= 1;
                bigBall.height -= 1;

            }

<fx:Declarations>
        <s:Move id="moveEffect" target="{bigBall}" xTo="90" repeatCount="1"
            effectStart="startScale();"
            effectEnd="endScale();"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

<MyComp:MyImg id="bigBall" source="@Embed(source='../images/ball1-1.png')"/>
```

I'am trying to move and scale an image, but the problem is that when I move it and then scale it, after the resizing the image returns to is initial position, and the next frame it appears again in the position that it has to go next, like a fast ping pong animation, how to avoid that?

Comment: Instead of modifying width/height in an enter frame listener (which I suspect causes some of the weirdness you're describing), you might try to use the the `Resize` effect in conjunction w/the `Move` effect. You can declare a `Parallel` effect that does both a move and resize in parallel... It's definitely the Flex way of doing this sort of thing as opposed to changing properties in an enter frame handler.

Answer (score 0):

From your incomplete code it is unable to get what you are actually trying to achieve. We can help more if you provide the complete code.

I think using `xBy="90"` instead of `xTo="90"` will solve your problem.